# Generating uniformly distributed trees

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics

I'm looking for closed (possibly approximate) formulae for the following problem.

I am trying to generate (uniformly distributed) random trees of a given size n. The "size" is the number of symbols in the tree, and I have fixed numbers of distinct nullary, unary and binary symbols available. To create a uniform distribution I need to know the number of trees of a certain characteristics, or at least their relative frequencies. "Uniform" means in this case that every possible tree of size n is picked with equal probability.

The trees can be seen as strings of symbols in Polish notation, and instead of just counting the full strings of a fixed size one can count prefixes of those strings with respect to a certain arity (number of holes in a tree, 0 holes is a complete tree).
These numbers obey a straightforward recurrence relation: if, at size n, we have $k_0$ tree fragments of arity 0, $k_1$ of arity 1, etc. (write it as n:[$k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3,...$]) then at size n+1 this list becomes:
n+1:[$z*k_1,u*k_1+z*k_2,u*k_2+b*k_1+z*k_3,u*k_3+b*k_2+z*k_4,...$], where z,u,b are the numbers of nullary, unary, and binary symbols - because a unary symbol does not change the arity of a tree, binary/nullary make it go up/down by 1, and trees of arity 0 cannot be further extended. For example, trees of arity 0 must have a nullary symbol in last position, so the number of those trees at size n+1 is z times the number of unary trees of size n.

I can use this recurrence to compute precise numbers, but they get huge quickly, and for large n the computation takes very long, as we are talking here arbitrary precision integers and exponential growth. (For n=10000, my computer is huffing and puffing for several minutes to compute those numbers. n=100000 would be hopeless.)

The kind of numbers I need to generate random trees are probabilities such as $\frac{u*k_2}{u*k_2+b*k_1+z*k_3}$, which in this case would be the probability that a prefix string of length n+1 and arity 2 has a unary function symbol in its last position. So, are there closed formulae that describe the numbers of those tree fragments (or their relative proportions)?

Comment: Are these labelled or unlabelled trees?  The question is, what trees count as "the same" or "different"?

Comment: I didn't understand the problem in detail, but for practical use it might be sufficient to calculate the number to floating-point precision.

Comment: Search for "Boltzmann sampling" for some approximate algorithms.

Comment: These are generalizations of Catalan numbers, and there should be explicitish formulas in terms of multinomial coefficients.

Comment: In particular, the number of such trees of size $n$ with $n_0,n_1,n_2$ nodes of respective arities $0,1,2$ (which can only happen if $n=n_0+n_1+n_2=1+n_1+2n_2$) is $\frac1n\binom n{n_0,n_1,n_2}z^{n_0}u^{n_1}b^{n_2}$, since each string with the right number of occurrences of nullary, unary, and binary symbols has exactly one cyclic permutation that is a correct Polish notation for a tree.

Comment: The trees are only labelled with the function symbols. Two trees are the same if they have the same shape and the same labelling with function symbols. "calculate to floating point precision" is not applicable here, as we ran out of exponents, e.g. the one number I mentioned I computed was roughly 10^8000.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I did come up with a formula for the size, but the problem is that the formula is a sum, indexed by varying values for $n_1$, because for every two unary symbols I add to the degree profile a binary and a nullary symbol is taken out. Each summand of this is then a multiple of the Catalan number for the number of binary symbols. I call this "a problem", because the sums are not any easier to compute than the recurrences, and there is very little room for simplification when computing the quotients for the probabilities.

Comment: Assuming your trees are ordered (labeled or not), there is a simple (and very efficient) algorithm to sample them uniformly. See M. D. Atkinson, ["Uniform Generation of Rooted Ordered Trees with Prescribed Degrees"](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/36.6.593),
The Computer Journal 36 (1993), 593–594.

Comment: 10^8000 is not a problem.  Use pairs $(d,i)$ where $d$ is double-precision and $i$ is integer. This represents $d\times 10^i$. I do this often. The only question is whether enough precision is maintained.